# Changing escape character for quotes

Tags: supercsv

I am trying to read a CSV file which contains escaped quote values such as:

```
"1","unquoted text","\"quoted text\""
```

It seems that SuperCSV wants quotes to be quoted as

```
"1","unquoted text","""quoted text"""
```

Is there a way to change the escape character to a backslash? I've looked at the docs and not seen anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just found a link to an issue logged in github: https://github.com/super-csv/super-csv/issues/14

Seems like a different CSV handler is in order.